# Chrome webdriver cannot connect to the service chromedriver.exe on Windows

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Hello !

I am currently using Selenium with Python on Windows 7, and I tried to use the Chrome webdriver for the hide function `--no-startup-window`. After I installed Chrome (x86), copied chromedriver.exe on path `C:\Python27\Scripts\` and added it on PATH environment, I tried to launch it via the following code:

```
opt = Options()
opt.add_argument("--no-startup-window")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opt)
```

However, I have the following error when I execute it:

```
(env) c:\opt\project\auto\>python program_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program_test.py", line 234, in <module>
    main()
  File "program_test.py", line 36, in main
    initChromeWebDriver()
  File "c:\opt\project\auto\common\driver.py", line 32, in initChromeWebDriver
    service_log_path=)
  File "c:\opt\project\auto\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.p
y", line 61, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "c:\opt\project\auto\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py"
, line 88, in start
    raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service chromedriver
```

Note: I am currently using a `virtualenv` also, so I also copied the chromedriver.exe on his `Scripts` folder. Any idea about the issue here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first , instead of using **Options()** method you should use **webdriver.ChromeOptions()** method to have the result that you want, secondly you should specify the **path to the Chromedriver** installed on your computer.

for example put chormedriver.exe file on drive C:\ and use:

```
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-startup-window")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chrome_options)

    driver.get("www.google.com")
```

Comment: Ok this solved my first issue here, however I now have an `unknown error: Chrome failed to start` when I use the `--no-startup-window`. Also, Chrome is launching when I comment this option. I updated my post for the error.

Comment: @toshiro92 why do you want to open the chrome without startup windows, could you explain?